# Lenovo A8 Android Tablet froze. The reset button did not reset

Tags: crashes, system-freeze, lenovo

My Lenovo A8 Android tablet froze without any reason. I had purchased it a week ago. The previous night it was working just perfectly. Then I put it aside and went to sleep. Today I slided its screen lock and it worked. The list of apps appeared. I tapped on my desired app, but nothing worked ever since.

I found a solution online to RESET the tablet, using the tiny button besides the SIM card. I pushed that tiny button, and the tablet went off immediately (no need to hold it down). However, unlike the online solution, it did not restart, but just got shut down.

I started it again using its power button. It started to show a small video of Lenovo and played its song. Then at the screen with the motto "Lenovo, for those who do" came at the end of the video, it froze again.

I pushed that tiny button for several times, and the exactly same thing happened. It just shut down the device, and when I manually restarted it, it froze at the very same stage again.

My questions are:

1. Why does it happen?
2. How to fix or unfreeze it? I don't want to Factory-Reset my device by holding volume up and down keys etc because I have a lot of app data. I want a soft reset.